# dynamic_sidebar write "1" after all widgets

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

My problem is that for some reason, a "1" appears after all the widgets. It does not matter what kind of widget I put in area or number of widgets. This does not happen when there's no widgets at all.

In functions.php:

```
function header_widgets_init() {
register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => 'Header',
    'id' => 'header_area',
    'before_widget' => '',
    'after_widget'  => '',
    'before_title'  => '',
    'after_title'   => '' 
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'header_widgets_init' );
```

In header.php:

```
<?php echo dynamic_sidebar( 'header_area' ); ?>
```

Comment: You should be looking at the code that prints/shows the widgets as the code you've supplied won't supply that information to help debug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the "**echo**" command.

Need to write `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'header_area' ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

My Answer:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'header_area' ); ?>
```

or

```
echo !dynamic_sidebar( 'header_area' );
```